Exim Sieve forum or references?
I'm migrating from Postfix + Dovecot with ManageSieve, to Exim, which has the Exim-specific implementation of Sieve. Is there a forum or guide for converting Sieve filters from the Dovecot version (Pidgeonhole) to the Exim version? Maybe a beginners' tutorial that documents current available features?
I have read the README and caveats in the Exim repo. That's not what I mean.
The Dovecot implementation supports many extensions that I use in scripts. I'm not sure that Exim fully supports equivalents.
As examples:

This is a common require statement:

require ["body", "copy", "envelope", "fileinto", "imap4flags", "include", "mailbox", "regex", "reject", "subaddress", "variables", "vnd.dovecot.debug"];

I use a lot of global variables between scripts.
I extensively include scripts.

I make use of :global and :personal locations when including. I don't see a reference to a sieve_global config variable for Exim (because, no ManageSieve).
I know Exim uses .forward files rather than .sieve and .svbin, and I don't see anything about linking/including these files.



Yes, some of those extensions and related features are supported. Others not. Aside from loading up scripts and seeing what errors are generated , is there a better way to pro-actively find out what isn't supported so that I can re-code and test? I saw a list of extensions in the Exim code but I got the impression I was missing some details.
I'm porting the scripts from my own server where I have shell/root access to a hosted environment with only SFTP using an account user. So I do not have the benefit of sievec (though I can get shell access if required). In other words, blackbox testing would be painful, and I'd rather do this with more fore-knowledge than in the school of hard knocks.
